# Modify HTML Markup of md-datepicker Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I'm using `md-datepicker` in my page. I have a requirement wherein I need to add a CSS class to the rendered `input` element. Is there a way to modify the markup generated by `md-datepicker`?

```
<md-content>            
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
</md-content>
```

PS: Adding a CSS class is just a simple use case scenario. There is a chance that more complex modifications might be required in future. Hence, I'm looking for a way to have control over the HTML of the material design if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to modify rendered HTML directly.
You can check the [source code](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/datepicker/datePicker.js) to figure out the exact rendered HTML and the logic behind it. You can notice for example that the input have the class `"md-datepicker-input"`. If you want to add a class, all you can do is to add a class to your `md-datepicker` tag (let's say 'my-class'), and then make appropriate selector in your css, for example: `md-datepicker.my-class input.md-datepicker-input`